# Issues using Early Bound classes with PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics 1.0.9 library in .NET 6

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dataverse, early-binding

I have managed to generate early bound classes using the CrmSvcUtil code generation tool:

[image]

But the highlighted assembly ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute is causing issues when trying to establish a connection with my organization through Dataverse with following exception;

```
InvalidOperationException: Resolved assembly's simple name should be the same as of the requested assembly.
```

[image]

When I remove the highlighted assembly code-line, it can succesfully establish the connection.

The referenced library looks correct since it is pointing at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client (1.0.9) which I also use to establish the connection.

[image]

Comment: I got a problem similar to yours. What I did was creating a console application that uses the Roslyn library (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp) in order to get rid of the lines generated from CrmSvcUtil that I don't need. I use the CrmSvcUtil classes as my input and that console application creates a similar output according to my needs.